# How to do `cd` and invoke some npm scripts inside csh/sh script?

Tags: node.js, linux, webpack, csh

I am a complete newbie to linux and CSH Scripts, I am currently working on a UI Project with reactjs + node + npm + webpack.

As you may now, i need to run webpack bundling to get complied files.

My project is being deployed on a linux machine.

This is my project structure as shown below,

[image: Project]

I need to write a csh script in uibuild.csh file as show above,

So this is what i think pseudocode would be,

The script will be executed from

> project/web-inf/scripts/uibuild.csh

1. Need to check Node.js and Npm installed or Not,
    if installed contine
    else exit and throw error
2. Next, i need to change directory to project/uisrc/
3. Next, i need to execute the below commands serially

> 'npm install'
>   'npm run build'

4. Next, when the npm run build is successful, build files will located inside project/uisrc/dist/ folder. (i need to check files are there or not here).
5. After that, i need to move the files from project/uisrc/dist to project/ folder.
6. then i need to remove the node_modules folder generated inside the path project/uisrc/node_modules
7. Exit script with no-error

As of now, i have tried checking node installed or not by using this script.

```
 if(`where node` == "") then
      printf "\nNode.js and Npm not installed. Please install and continue\n";
      exit(1);
   endif
```

But i dunno how to change directory and run scripts ??

Can you someone solve this ?

If you need more details, i happy to provide.

Comment: Wow, csh. I didn't know that was still around. (I just checked; csh is not even installed on my linux machine.)

Comment: :) :) Thats the process they are following here. S**ks. May be i can change it to sh. let me rename the title.

Comment: BTW, if you haven't seen this yet: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) (1994, good times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if which node > /dev/null ; then
  printf 'Node.js & NPM installed, continue start builing.. \n'
else
  printf '\x1B[31m Node.js & NPM is not installed, exiting now.. \x1B[0m \n'
  exit 0;
fi

printf 'Current working Directory :: '
pwd
cd ../../uisrc/
printf 'Current working Directory :: '
pwd
cd dist/
rm -rf index.html assets fixtures
cd ..
npm install --verbose
npm run build
cd ..
rm -rf index.html assets fixtures
cd uisrc/
mv dist/* ../
```